# Проблемы с wi-fi win10 64bit

Tags: wifi

Стояла 7 винда, вай фай время от времени то работал то нет, писало "беспроводная сеть отключена", все варианты проделал распространенные с дровами, всяко разными обновами, управление электропитанием, отключал галочку на то чтобы не обрубался при малом заряде ноута. В службах все ок. Дрова новые все. Установил 10 винду , ничего не изменилось, то работает то нет. Все тоже самое проделывал. Далее что делал чтобы хотя бы он заработал на время. В диспетчер устройств заходил удалял там wifi адаптер, вырубал ноут, запускал, но уже со включенным инетом по проводу. Все работало, вай фай подключался, шнур потом отключал и все норм было, если удалять адаптер из диспетчера и включать без инета, то не работает. Включил с инетом, все работает, думал проблемы в дровах, но перезагрузив опять, он не работал вновь. Иногда бывало конечно что после перезагрузки инет работал, но единичные случаи. Все перепробовал, что делать? Уточню, на клавиатуре сочетание клавиш включения и выключения вайфая нету, только режим полета, но это я уже пробовал, без успеха, физических кнопок на корпусе тоже нету.

Comment: Какой драйвер, какая карточка? Вы тут поплакать пришли или решение искать?

Comment: Себя слышишь? уже писал, что дрова все новые стоят и точно дело не в них. так как при перезагрузке wifi может работать, а может и нет. В диспетчере устройств находил этот модуль и с инета с офф сайта качал дрова. Расписал все подробно... что не понятно из слов "дрова новые все"? Как раз пришел за решением, а не поплакать.. и не хотелось бы видеть такие сообщения, похожие на твои, потому что помощи от таких 0.

Comment: Новый это какой? Рилтек, ахерос, интел? С офсайта кого? Производителя пк или карточки? Букв в сообщении много, а деталей никаких. Даже модели ноута нет.

Comment: хотелось бы видеть вопросы содержащие какие-то детали. На то что есть можно ответить "у меня на виндовс 10 таких проблем нет - сдай по гарантии или в сервисный центр"

Comment: Изготовитель wifi адаптера: Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Название устройства: Realtek RTL8723BE 82.11 bgn WI-FI Adapter
Драйвер скачан с этого сайта: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8723be-software
Модель ноута: HP Notebook